# How to display color icons in menu, PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qmenu

What i'm trying to achieve is to display color icons in a context menu, in python. So that it displays some of the used colors to mark the table.

Here is an example of what i'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Any guess how to do this ?

**UPDATE**
Here is a more detailed version of my vision.

On clicking Mark , a sub menu opens up with color options.

[image]

Comment: what is the context menu, is it wen you click the arrow beside A with red bar, the panel under shows up, when click again the panel disappears?

Comment: @Schollii : No , its the menu that pops up , when you press right click on the mouse.

Comment: @Schollii : The above given image is just an example , i wanted to show what i meant by color icons .

Comment: yes, I wasn't clear, I know what a context menu is, I was trying to understand what context menu you are trying to build, it's actually not clear (to me!) from the image. So if you right click on some object in your GUI you want a menu to show up that has several rows, each with a color icon beside it? Maybe it would be easier to actually show exactly what you are look for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily using a [QWidgetAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidgetaction.html).

The example code below uses tool-buttons with icons for the grid of colors, but there are many other widgets could just as easily be be used. The `palette` method can be reimplemented if you need a different set of colors.

```
class ColorAction(QtGui.QWidgetAction):
    colorSelected = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QColor)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QWidgetAction.__init__(self, parent)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(widget)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        palette = self.palette()
        count = len(palette)
        rows = count // round(count ** .5)
        for row in range(rows):
            for column in range(count // rows):
                color = palette.pop()
                button = QtGui.QToolButton(widget)
                button.setAutoRaise(True)
                button.clicked[()].connect(
                    lambda color=color: self.handleButton(color))
                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(16, 16)
                pixmap.fill(color)
                button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(pixmap))
                layout.addWidget(button, row, column)
        self.setDefaultWidget(widget)

    def handleButton(self, color):
        self.parent().hide()
        self.colorSelected.emit(color)

    def palette(self):
        palette = []
        for g in range(4):
            for r in range(4):
                for b in range(3):
                    palette.append(QtGui.QColor(
                        r * 255 // 3, g * 255 // 3, b * 255 // 2))
        return palette

class ColorMenu(QtGui.QMenu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QMenu.__init__(self, parent)
        self.colorAction = ColorAction(self)
        self.colorAction.colorSelected.connect(self.handleColorSelected)
        self.addAction(self.colorAction)
        self.addSeparator()
        self.addAction('Custom Color...')

    def handleColorSelected(self, color):
        print(color.name())
```